# Difference between "evaluate as" and "evaluate to"

Tags: verbs, mathematics

Does the expression 1+1 evaluate *as* 2 or does it evaluate *to* 2?

Is one (or both) of the above not proper English or misused in this context, or are they both okay?

Answer (score 1):

Google Books (don't use vanilla Google) shows both work for digits for value:

"**expression evaluates to 5**"
About 65 results

"expression evaluates as 5"
3 results

I'd prefer the "to" variant.

With literals for values (a, b, u), only t seems to work; I just wasn't able get any hits with "as." Others might know otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I would use only "to".  "As" implies something like "in the guise or form of" and doesn't convey a the same sense of exactness as "to".